# ManagerId field on User object is coming null

Tags: trigger

I have a SOQL query inside my one of trigger

```
User newOwner = [SELECT ManagerId FROM User WHERE Id=:newCase.OwnerId];
```

But this query returns ManagerId Null. I checked manually, Manager is defined on owner record.

This soql returns null only when context user is a partner user. As a salesforce user it works fine.

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: is the owner the one you expect ? maybe there are assignment rules executed after your trigger, and in your trigger scope the Owner is not the one finally set on the Case...

Comment: Yes, OwnerId is coming fine. If I paste that Id in url it takes to me the correct user. Manager is populated there.

Comment: Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: @amatorVitae I have also checked that. Permission is given.

Comment: This query returns null when context user is partner user. Otherwise it works fine i.e. from salesforce user.

Comment: Field level security? Make sure the partner profile can see the field...

Comment: Yes I checked that. Permission is given by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom formula field on User object `ManagerId__c` which refers standard `ManagerId`. Inside my trigger, I used `ManagerId__c` instead of `ManagerId`. It works out for me.